# France business visa rejection twice , should I apply again

Tags: visa-refusals, international-travel, france, visa-rejections, french-language

I had applied for a France business Visa in June 2019 with all documents required like invitation letter, cover letter, travel itinerary , my payslips and ITR for 3 years and travel insurance and good amount of savings...but visa was rejected stating "the information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of stay was not reliable".
Then my employer sent an email in French to the French consulate in Mumbai asking what could be the possible reason for the refusal to which they replied and said to reapply with all documents and to share the email chat between them while reapplying...and still the French consulate rejected stating the same reason when I reapplied in thr month of July...I am unable to figure out what exactly is happening and what should I do in this case.Should I stop applying again or remonstrate or what can be done I am completely clueless.

Comment: You should stop applying and figure out what the problem is before applying again. The linked question and answer will help you determine what the problem is.

Comment: @Michael Hampton - How do i figure out ? when the consulate people only ask to reapply stating everything is fine.All required documents were in place but still its being rejected.
- Invitation letter was on the company letter head with details of what will happen with whom.
- Travel itinerary and stay , travel insurance and payslips and bank statement of 3 months with more than required balance was also there.My sponsor was highly reputed that would impact my case,no forged documents.But i had dummy flight tickets, would that have been a possible cause of refusal?

Comment: @Smallik34 Do you mean to say that you submitted fake airplane tickets with your application? In that case of course that may have been the reason for the visa refusals.

Comment: @undercat it wasn't fake , it was a dummy air ticket that gets auto cancelled within 3-4 days.It was a travel itinerary.